# How to show PDF from base64 String

Tags: android, pdf, base64

I am receiving an encoded base64 string for a PDF file and I would to show it inside a fragment with a Floating Action button that can be used for saving or printing the pdf.

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629022/how-to-show-pdf-from-base64-string-on-android) but it didn't work out for me because it was complaining about `exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`. It probably has something to do with the write access. I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` in my Manifest but I also have a warning that `write_external_storage no longer provides write access when targeting android 10+`.

Anyhow, in that solution, it tries to save the pdf first then open it. Is there any way around it? To just simply show the pdf and then provide a button to save it?

Screenshot of what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: If you want in-app PDF rendering, there is `PdfRenderer` in the Android SDK, but it cannot handle arbitrary PDFs. There are also PDF rendering libraries, like [this one](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer).

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. Can I use base64 String with that lib?

Comment: You would need to decode the base-64 encoded data. This is not significantly different than with any other data that for whatever bizarre reason is base-64 encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by using [this library](https://github.com/mhiew/AndroidPdfViewer)

Add following to your build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.mhiew:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

Add the following to your layout

```
<com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/app_bar" />
```

Then simply decode the base64 string and pass it to the pdfView as follow

```
private fun renderPdf(base64EncodedString: String) = try {
    val decodedString = Base64.decode(base64EncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT)
    binding.pdfView.fromBytes(decodedString).load()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    // handle error
}
```